# OpenAPI add server at Server Start

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, swagger-3.0

I try to modify server list (or default server) on Swagger UI.
1/ On Spring (Not Spring Boot) configuration class I add this :

```
    @Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    log.info("<<<customOpenAPI>>>");
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setUrl("http://localhost:8091/eatery_spring_rs/rs/");
    return new OpenAPI()
            .servers(List.of(server));
}
```

2/ But I never obtain result on Swagger UI, no server is added :
[image]

3/ Maven dependencies are :

```
<!--SWAGGER-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- END -->
```

5/ Question :
Is it possible to change context path, or add server URL, by program ?

Comment: Not sure why you need the Springfox dependency if you already have Springdoc, assuming you also have the required spring dependencies.

Comment: You true, I have tried with springdoc-openapi-ui alone, but result remain the same

Comment: 6/ I can affine the description of problem

Answer (score 0):

6/ I can affine the description of problem
The context path of application is not complete
It is a Spring 5.3 application, start with **web.xml** in App Server.
like Tomcat, ...
This is the web.xml definition :

`

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:servlet-service.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

This mean that the real context path is : [app.context]**/rs** but in the case of :
`@Bean public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) {`

servletContext is equal to **[app.context]** NOT to **[app.context]/rs**

It's help ?